# Implementing back navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I've got a top bar with `IconButton` for handling back navigation when clicked.

Function passed as callback's implemented like this:

```
private fun navigateBack(navController: NavController) {
    val route = navController.previousBackStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: ""
    navController.navigate(route)
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not working the same as the default android bottom navigation shown in the picture

[image]

Is there a way to implement the same back navigation as bottom system navigation has?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass your `NavController` to your `TopAppBar` and use `navController.navigateUp()` in the navigation icon.

If you want to show this icon only in some composables you can use a parameter, like `canPop` in the following example, and set it true in the composable where you want handle the back button.

```
if (canPop) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text(text = title) },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                navController.navigateUp()
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Rounded.ArrowBack, "")
            }
        },
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.TopBarColor)
} else {
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text(text = title) },
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.TopBarColor
    )
}
```

Check also [popBackStack documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack())

> Attempts to pop the controller's back stack. Analogous to when the user presses the system Back button when the associated navigation host has focus.

Comment: @Paul9999 It's just a variable I was using to determine if the screen should have or not the back navigation button. It's not important in the context of the question.